# ElementCollection inside Embeddable inside MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I have problems with persisting the following construct with JPA.

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class SuperFoo {
    @Embedded
    private Bar bar;

    public SuperFoo() {}

    public SuperFoo(...) {
        ...
        this.bar = new Bar("barKey");
    }

    ...

    public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

```java
@Embeddable
public class Bar {
    @ElementCollection
    Map<String, Long> durations;

    @ElementCollection
    Map<String, Integer> integers;

    public Bar() {}

    public Bar(String barKey) {
         his.durations = new HashMap<String, Long>();
         this.integers = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

         durations.put(key, new Long(15));
         integers.put(key, new Integer(10));
    }

    ... setters and getters.....
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Foo extends SuperFoo {
    @Id
    private String id;

    public Foo() {}

    public Foo(String id, *superArguments*) {
        super(*superArguments*);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Entity
public class FooContainer {
    @Id
    String id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Foo> fooList;

    public FooContainer() {}

    public FooContainer(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fooList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.fooList.add(foo);
    }

    public void setFooList(List<Foo> fooList) {this.fooList = fooList;}

    public List<Foo> getFooList() { return fooList; }
}
```

Method where persisting takes place:

```java
public void method() {
    FooContainer fooContainer = fooContainerRepository.getOne(...);
    fooContainer.addFoo(new Foo(...));
    fooContainerRepository.save(fooContainer);
}
```

JPA creates the following tables (looks fine):

- foo
- foo_durations
- foo_integers

Now, when I save an instance of Foo, everything gets persisted (fields in Foo). **BUT I get no entries in foo_durations and foo_integers.** Furthermore, I get no exceptions.

I did a little research myself and found the following:
*"An embeddable class that is contained within an element collection must not contain an element collection."*

I think, here, that is not the case because my embeddable class "Bar" is not contained within an element collection. So does anybody know, what I might have done wrong?
Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
I forgot to mention that the Bar Object inside SuperFoo is not set via constructor but calculated inside the constructor.

Comment: Can you put a short piece of code how you construct `Foo` and persist it?

Comment: I updated the Foo class and the SuperFoo class in the question.

Comment: So how is `Bar` calculated? Also I'm not sure if your JPA provider supports persisting `Duration`. You could test this with `Long` instead of `Duration` just to see if it is the case?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I changed it to Long, same result. In the description, I added the logic in the Bar class and a FooContainer, which contains a List with Foos. I forgot to mention that, too.

Comment: When not calculating the Maps in the Bar constructor, but setting the values explicitly, I get the same result. No entries in the foo_durations and foo_integers tables.